# Have anyone worked on Neoload?

Tags: neoload

**How does variablization and variable extraction works out in Neo-load.
How to identify Dynamic Value and parameters.**

How does regular expressions works

Answer (score 2):

Did you see these  [Neoload tutorials videos](http://www.neotys.com/product/demo-neoload.html)

Also in the technical publication, in [Regular Expressions](http://www.neotys.com/documents/doc/neoload/latest/en/html/#472.htm) section explain and post some examples:

- [Extracting a URL Parameter Value](http://www.neotys.com/documents/doc/neoload/latest/en/html/#481.htm)
- [Extracting a Form Parameter Value](http://www.neotys.com/documents/doc/neoload/latest/en/html/#482.htm)
- [Extracting HTTP Headers](http://www.neotys.com/documents/doc/neoload/latest/en/html/#488.htm)
- [Common Errors & Tips](http://www.neotys.com/documents/doc/neoload/latest/en/html/#490.htm)

Comment: No, I am not but I did some testing with it.